# ROS C++ Approximate Time Synchronizer callback not working in node member class (sync goes out of scope)

Tags: c++, callback, ros, synchronized

I've been trying to solve this for a while without success. Basically I have a node with several class members and in one of those classes I need to process data from 3 synced topics. I am using Approximate Time Synchronizer. My problem is that the synced callback only gets called once or twice and then stops (sync goes out of scope).

I'll put a simplified version of the node below. The structure is node.cpp instanciates member class A. Class A has a multi-threaded loop. Inside that loop I instanciate ClassB, declare the subscribers and Approximate synchronizer and set the callback for the synchronizer to point to ClassB's function so I can process that data in class B.

I don't know where to create the synchronizer. First I tried having it directly in class B but declaring it in classB's constructor or one of classB's functions got only 1 successful call before sync was destroyed.

As you see below in classA.cpp, now I have put the sync in the loop function where i get it to successfully callback a few times but it eventually stops. I would like to put it in the main funcion of node.cpp like in this example, but I need to pass to the callback the ClassB environment and I need to do that after a bunch of other things happen in Class A.

I appreciate your advice!

node.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <node/ClassA.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "node");
   tf2_ros::Buffer buffer(ros::Duration(10));
   tf2_ros::TransformListener tf(buffer);
   node::ClassA lcr("node", buffer);
   ros::spin();
   return (0);
}
```

class A.h:

```
#include <node/classB.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <msgs/msgType.h>

using namespace message_filters;

namespace node
{
    Class A
   {
    public: 
        ClassA();
       ~ClassA();
    protected:
        Object* b_;
    private:
        void loop(node::Config &config, double frequency);
        ClassB * b_;
        message_filters::Subscriber<msgs::msgType> subscriber_A;
        message_filters::Subscriber<msgs::msgType> subscriber_B;
        message_filters::Subscriber<msgs::msgType> subscriber_C;
        typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<msgs::msgType, msgs::msgType, msgs::msgType> MySyncPolicy;
        typedef Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> Sync;
        boost::shared_ptr<Sync> sync;
    };
}
```

ClassA.cpp:

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>

using namespace message_filters;

namespace node
{
    ClassA::ClassA():
         thread_shutdown_(false)
    { // Constructor for classA
    }
     ClassA::~ClassA(){
          thread_shutdown_ = true;
    }

    objectB_ = new Object ();
    function1();
   }

   void ClassA::function1(){
       // ...
        thread_ = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ClassA::loop, this, config, loop_frequency));
   }

   void ClassA::loop(node::NodeConfig &config, double frequency){
       ros::NodeHandle nh;

       ros::NodeHandle nh_B("~/" + name_);
       ClassB * b_ = new ClassB(&nh_B, objectB_); // Initialize ClassB instance

       subscriber_A.subscribe(nh_v2x, "topic1", 1);
       subscriber_B.subscribe(nh_v2x, "topic2", 1);
       subscriber_C.subscribe(nh_v2x, "topic3", 1);
       sync.reset(new Sync(MySyncPolicy(20), subscriber_A, subscriber_B, subscriber_C));
       sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClassB::subscribe_synced_callback, b_, _1, _2, _3)); // this gets callback called twice

       while (nh.ok() && !thread_shutdown_)
       {
           //sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClassB::subscribe_synced_callback, b_, _1, _2, _3)); // this gets callback called a few times and then stops
        // do stuff
       }
   }
}
```

ClassB.h:

```
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>

using namespace message_filters;

namespace node
{
    class ClassB
    {
    //...
    public:
        ClassB();
        ~ClassB();
        void subscribe_synced_callback(const msgs::msgType::ConstPtr& msgA, const msgs::msgType::ConstPtr& msgB, const msgs::msgType::ConstPtr& msgC);
        //...
    };
}
```

ClassB.cpp:

```
#include <node/classB.h>

namespace node
{
   ClassB::ClassB(){ // Constructor for classB
    // ...
   }

   void ClassB::subscribe_synced_callback(const msgs::msgTpye::ConstPtr& msgA, const msgs::msgType::ConstPtr& msgB, const msgs::msgType::ConstPtr& msgC)
   {
       // Do stuff with Time synced data
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot the example link: https://gist.github.com/tdenewiler/e2172f628e49ab633ef2786207793336#file-sync_example-cpp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, right off the bat, I'm going to say, as a matter of style you should try to separate out  your ros code and you classes/real code. You should put all the real work in your classes, then call them from a node executable, that wraps them, and does io with other nodes. Also, you don't need to have a node be a class, you can just make it a single file. This helps simplify & concentrate all your ros definitions in one place.

```
// ROS Includes
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

// Custom Includes
#include <my_pkg/classA.h>

// Subscribers
//   left_img (sensor_msgs/Image): "camera/left"
//   right_img (sensor_msgs/Image): "camera/right"

// ROS Handles and Publishers
ros::NodeHandle* nh;
ros::NodeHandle* pnh;

// ROS Callbacks
static void img_cb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& left_img_msg, const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& right_img_msg);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "synchronizer");
  nh = new ros::NodeHandle();
  pnh = new ros::NodeHandle("~");

  // Subscribers
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> left_img_sub(*nh, "camera/left", 10);
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> right_img_sub(*nh, "camera/right", 10);
  typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> MySyncPolicy;
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> img_sync(MySyncPolicy(10), left_img_sub, right_img_sub);
  img_sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&img_cb, _1, _2));
  ros::spin();
}

static void img_cb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& left_img_msg, const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& right_img_msg){
  ROS_INFO("Synchronization successful");
  // Real code from classes here
}
```

This is the best that I could fatham from your code, but it does seem that you've already seen the [relevant ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters).